# Byte conversion in Linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

please help me in Linq. i am completely new in linq. please see my code below.

```
    public Entities.ServiceResult<Customer> CustomerChangePassword(string CustomerId, string OldPassword, string NewPassword)
    {
        long _customerId = Convert.ToInt32(CustomerId);
        byte _oldPassword = Convert.ToByte(OldPassword);
        var _result = (from c in context.customers where (c.CustomerId == _customerId && c.Password == _oldPassword) select c.Password.Single).SingleOrDefault();

        if (_result != null)
        {
            string newpassword;
            newpassword = Convert.ToString(_result.Password);
            newpassword = NewPassword;
            context.SaveChanges();
            return new Entities.ServiceResult<Customer>
            {
                ErrorState = 0,
                Message = "Password Changed Successfully."
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new Entities.ServiceResult<Customer>
            {
                ErrorState = 1,
                Message = "Old Password Is Wrong."
            };
        }
    }
```

the above code i am doing a change password functionality. in this code c.Password is byte column, and i am passing from mobile as string. in this case how to handle this. please help me to do this

Comment: Theres an obvious issue with the "newpassword" variable. You make it and convert to string, overwrite it with the content of NewPassword and expect the context to know you've changed the password somehow.

Comment: here the problem is for c.Password == OldPassword this line. getting message like Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'byte'

Comment: Also - converting to byte, is going to fail - password would need to be a number < 255 I think

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to check the password in finding the customer. That's because your are dealing with an IQueriable and you can not do this kind od job easily there. Also you should change the password in place to tell the context to save it for you.
Consider the code for Converting string to byte array as well.
With SequenceEqual method you check the equality of two arrays.

I hope the following code helps :

```
    public Entities.ServiceResult<Customer> CustomerChangePassword(string CustomerId, string OldPassword, string NewPassword)
    {
        long _customerId = Convert.ToInt32(CustomerId);
        byte[] _oldPassword = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(OldPassword);
        var _result = from c in context.customers where (c.CustomerId == _customerId) select c;

        if (_result == null || _result.Count() == 0)
        {
            return new Entities.ServiceResult<Customer>
            {
                ErrorState = 1,
                Message = "User does not exists."
            };
        }

        var customer = _result.First();
        if (!customer.Password.SequenceEqual(_oldPassword))
        {
            return new Entities.ServiceResult<Customer>
            {
                ErrorState = 1,
                Message = "Old Password Is Wrong."
            };
        }
        customer.Password = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(NewPassword);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return new Entities.ServiceResult<Customer>
        {
            ErrorState = 0,
            Message = "Password Changed Successfully."
        };
    }
```

Good Luck.